# How to tune parameters of Bagging in R?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, bagging

I was wondering when we use the Bagging to do the classification, what parameters can be tuned and can we use the cross-validation to tune it?

In the [Bagging function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ipred/versions/0.4-0/topics/bagging) in R, it says we can use the nbagg to change the number of bootstrap replications. And use [rpart.control](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-11/topics/rpart.control).But other than these two, what else can I use for tuning?

Here's my code  bagging(income ~., data = training3, coob= T)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what base learners you are bagging. Of course, you always have the parameters of the base learners, plus how many boostrap samples to use (the more the better, but you will hit a plateau).